# Stored procedure executing but not able to populate gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, stored-procedures

I need to populate a gridview upon user login. I have written a stored procedure for populating that gridview using login credentials... my stored procedure is working ... I'm able to get the output in SQL Server but once I use login id and password and logs in gridview isn't getting populated... please help me out..

This is my codes and stored procedure

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetManager]
    @EmpName nvarchar(50)
AS
  SELECT
      TaskName, DueDate, Description, AssignBy, AssignTo, Status, PercentageComplete
  FROM
      dbo.Task, dbo.EmployeeData
  WHERE
      AssignTo IN (SELECT EmpName FROM EmployeeData WHERE Manager = 'RS') 
      AND AssignBy IN (SELECT EmpName FROM EmployeeData WHERE Manager = 'RS')
      AND EmpName = @EmpName;
```

I'm using 3 layered architecture.. wich has DTO,DAL and business layer.. I'm calling data source through these layers.

Backend code

DAL :

```
public DataSet GetManager(MTMSDTO M)
{
        DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
        SqlParameter objParam = new SqlParameter("@EmpName", M.EmpName);
        objParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        objParam.Size = 50;

        db.Parameters.Add(objParam);
        return db.ExecuteDataSet("GetManager");
}
```

BusinessLayer :

```
public DataSet GetManager(MTMSDTO M)
{
        MTMSAccess obj = new MTMSAccess();
        return obj.GetManager(M);
}
```

Gridview calling function using stored procedure:

```
protected void GrdManager()
{
           MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();
           {
            objc.EmpName = Convert.ToString(Session["EmpName"]);
            DataSet GrdMA = obj.GetManager(objc);
            DataView GrdMan = new DataView();
            GrdMan.Table = GrdMA.Tables[0];
            GridViewTTlist.DataSource = GrdMan;
            GridViewTTlist.DataBind();
           }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the length of name string? might be it would be more than the size of the parameter.

Comment: can u please elobrate it ... i didnt et u...lenght f name string in sql server ?

Comment: Please tell me the name which you are passing in the name parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected void GrdManager()
{
           MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();

            objc.EmpName = Convert.ToString(Session["EmpName"]);
            DataSet GrdMA = obj.GetManager(objc);
            GridViewTTlist.DataSource = GrdMA.Tables[0];
            GridViewTTlist.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: thnks guys i got d grid view displayed atlast... nt sure wat d prblm was .. but i removed my panel n tried displayng it and i got d result... n i checked the panel properties its nt hidden too...